# Can't connect to db - PlayFramework + Ebean

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

There was a lot of question about the same error, but those answers didn't help me.

Error is:

> [CompletionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programmatically via registerServer()]

The code which raise this error:

```
public Result newuser() {
    Form<UserAuth> userform = formFactory.form(UserAuth.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(userform.hasErrors()) {
        return landing();
    }

    userform.get().save();
    flash("success", "User " + userform.get().login + " has been added");
    return landing();
}
```

build.sbt:

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT" 
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
cache,
javaWs,
evolutions,
"com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap" % "1.1-P25-B3",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.21"
)
```

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.2")
```

application.conf:

```
play.evolutions {
   #db.default.enabled = false
}

play.db {
 config = "db"
 default = "typobank"

 prototype {
 # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
 #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
 #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
 pool = "default"
 driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 user=user
 password=pass
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/typobank"

 hikaricp {
  #connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
 }
 }
 }
 db {
    db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/typobank?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    db.default.username=hiddenuser
    db.default.password=pass
    ebean.default=["models.*"]
 }
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: I think I use the latest version, according to the "addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unbelievable, but after throwing away default config garbage, I've got everything working!

Here working pure config:

```
play.crypto.secret = "changeme"

play.i18n.langs = [ "en" ]

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/typobank?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.username=hiddenuser
db.default.password=pass

ebean.default=["models.*"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be enough application.conf like this:

```
db {
    default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    default.url="mysql://hiddenuser:pass@localhost/typobank?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    default.username=hiddenuser
    default.password=pass
}
ebean.default=["models.*"]
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried this fix, but this raise an exception during startup:
[image: this raise an exception during startup]

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
db {
  db.default...
}
```

evaluates to `db.db.default` and that is why it is not detected. This is the main reason at the first place. It must be

```
db {
  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/typobank?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  default.username=hiddenuser
  default.password=pass
}
```